# Comparision Calculator in DataStudio

Tags: data-visualization, looker-studio

Is it possible to show comparison metric for Google Data Studio Score cards. I want to show mom/yoy change.
[image: My input data has a timestamp which is in the format described in the image attached.]

I have parsed this "text" column using PARSE_DATE('%B/%Y', column name) and it now shows me unit purchased at the start of each month, I want to show the comparison to previous month but it shows "no data".

[image: I can very well observe that my values have been converted to date ranges because I can view the data type and constituent data here]

How do I put the comparison indicator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your requirement the ‘No data’ error is due to the following possibilities:

1- The one Possibility is with the wrong date column which you might have given in your ‘date range dimension’, You have to provide the Date column which should be in date format , not the one which is in “text” format.

2- The other Possibility is Incorrect comparison date range. When you are providing the data range you have to provide the full set of data for the time Period else it will throw you the error “No data”.

For your second query - Yes you can do the comparison metric in the Scorecard for Month over Month (MOM) as well as Year over Year (YOY)

Steps:

1- Create a scorecard for year1 with filter to choose that particular year only (say for example filter to choose year 2020)

2- Similarly create another scorecard for year2 with filter (say for example filter to select only year 2021)

3-Blend both the scorecards.

4-Customize the ratio.

you can refer to this public documentations also:

[No data Error](https://support.supermetrics.com/support/solutions/articles/19000078014-troubleshooting-no-data-found-errors)

[Date Ranges in Data Studio](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9272806?hl=en)

[scorecards](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7193479?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article)

[Blending](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9061421?hl=en)